# Sum of total values in blade laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-5.4

I have 5 arrays, each array contains `medicine_price`, `medicine_quantity`.
What I want is to add the result of each array.
The problem is, I cant get the correct result of each array.

Example:

```
result1 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity  
result2 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity
result3 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity
result4 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity
result5 = medicine_price * medicine_quantity

total = result1 + result2 + result3 + result4 + result5
```

This should be the result that I want.
And it is also possible that more array will be included since I have incremented them.

Code :

```
@php
    $i = 1;
    @endphp
    @foreach($carts as $cart)

    {!! $cart->medicine_quantity !!}

    @php
    $value=  $cart->medicine_price  * $cart->medicine_quantity;
    echo "<input type='hidden' id='sample$i' value='$value'>";

    $i++
    @endphp

    @endforeach

    @php
    echo "$Total_price"
    @endphp
```

Comment: You're multiplying this ` $cart->medicine_price  * $cart->medicine_quantity` not adding and can we please have those list of 5 array you've mentioned

Answer (score 5):

```
<div class="mx-auto"><strong>Total Number of Voters</strong> <p class="mx-3">{{$list->sum('voters')}}</p></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a more clean way to do this

Use mutators for a cart total

```
class Cart extends Model
{
    protected $appends = ['total_price'];

    public function getTotalPriceAttribute()
    {
        return $this->medicine_price * $this->medicine_quantity;
    }
}
```

Then access it `$cart->total_price`

And for carts total, you could use collection method `sum` like this

```
$total = $carts->sum('total_price');
```

Your blade view will be something like this

```
@foreach($carts as $cart)
{{ $cart->medicine_quantity }}
<input type='hidden' id='sample{{ $loop->index }}' value='{{ $cart->total_price }}'>
@endforeach

{{ $carts->sum('total_price') }}
```